# Show or hide form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have one html form - On that one text field like

```
<input type = "text" name = "age" value = "" id = "txt_age">
```

On the value of age i have to show this element like -

```
<select name = "married">
  <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value ="No">No</option>
</select>
```

If age>18 then married field will be shown to form otherwise hide it.This age>18 condition is stored in database.As value of age changes married field toggle(show/hide).
How can i do it with javascript/jquery.Please suggest.

For more information, all these fields are genereated dynamically.So i was thinking to add onchange = "somefuction(condition);" with age while creating  then look for field are to be shown when condition is satisfied, is also in DB.

OR

One solution may i think that -
The field in this case married will look for value of age changes.Then accordingly married will hide/show itself.But problem is that how married observe age field or call javascript function.
Sorry for not explaining full problem.

Comment: Call a **server-side** (if you need computation on server side because the condition is stored on DB) method on txt_age's change event (actually it's pretty elusive, focus may be better) posting the age. Return value may be a boolean value to indicate if "married" is enabled or not (add an ID too). A better solution ('cause I guess your UI could be more complicated than this) may include a full form's data post on every change and the return value may be a dictionary where each key is an element's ID and a couple of values to indicate if it's enabled and visible.

Comment: If only the threshold value is on the DB (18, in this case, because law may be different on different countries) you may simply use a hidden field (filled with the value from DB) as operand of the comparison (or even a simple replacement in the javascript code made on the server side).

Comment: Hi Adriano could you please explain what are you trying to say.This will be helpful to me.

Comment: If you do not need complex computations (with **rules** stored in the DB) you may simply pick one of the posted solutions. The "threshold" value (18 years) can't be hardcoded so you may use a hidden text field (filled with the value from the DB) and do comparison with that. Something like: if (parseInt($("#txt_age").val()) >= $("#min_age_get_married")) where min_age_get_married is <input type="hidden"...> filled on serverside with the right value.

Answer (score 1):

add id="married" to the select and use something like this.

```
$("#txt_age").blur(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).val() > 18) {
        $("#married").show();
    } else {
        $("#married").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hiya, minor issue, look at my code below: its not `id` its the `name` attribute that is given `:)`

Comment: I noted that in the answer.  Using name leaves the OP susceptible to having multiple elements on the page with the same name.  Better to just switch to an id.

Comment: Sorry , but i m not not looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this & note

- avoid the space between id = "txt_age"

rest this should help:

```
var $foo = $('select[name="married"]');
$foo.hide(); // in start always hide

$('#txt_age').on('blur', function() {
   if(parseInt(this.value)>18){
       $foo.hide();
   } else {
       $foo.show();
   }

});
```