# observe other field blur event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to observe other field blur event.
Suppose I have:

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age">
```

whose value is observe by other field like

```
<select name = "married" id = "married" someEvent = "function(par1, par2);">
   <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value ="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Function observes age field (i.e. blur event of age field).

Here question is that what event call that function which observes the blur event of age.Please help.
Above is just example I know I can do by using id's of field but this is not the same case every time.My id's, form elements and condition always change.

For reference my previous question is there - [Show or hide form element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503444/show-or-hide-form-element)

Comment: I find this question a little confusing, but maybe its just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you phrased your question it sounds like you want the select element to watch what happens with the input. That's not how html/JS events work. You need to attach an event handler to the input and within that handler do something to the select.

Using jQuery:

```
$("#age").on("blur", function() {
   // do something
});
```

Using an inline attribute like you already have for your select (I don't recommend this, but it seems to fit in with how you're already doing things):

```
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" onblur="someFunction(this);">

function someFunction(el) {
   // do something
}
```

> *"My id's, form elements and condition always change."*

You need some way to identify what elements to apply event handlers to. E.g., if you're not sure what ids might apply use a class:

```
<input type="text name="whatever" id="something" class="needsBlurEvent">

$(".needsBlurEvent").on("blur", function() {
   // do something
});
```

Comment: I want to call fuction from married field which carry some parameters,That fuction which observes age blur event.so...on what event of married field it is possible.

Comment: The Married field doesn't have an event that tells it when other fields blur. The general concept of one element observing another doesn't really apply to html/JS. Perhaps if you described what you want to happen from the user's point of view then we could explain how you'd go about coding that effect.

Comment: Ya.It is the one way i was thinking can you suggest any best option or other logic for this.

Comment: You haven't explained what you want to achieve. Describe what the user should see happening.

Comment: Please take look of my previous question.

Comment: Hi nnnnnn your answer is not usefull to me but i got clue from this answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery[.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```
​$('#age').blur(function(){
    alert('!!');
});​​​​​​​​
```

Here's your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jA3r4/).